# Is it possible to get the 100-reputation bonus for having a linked account with 200 rep after I've already signed up?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts, account-association

I heard you can get a 100-reputation bonus for creating a new Stack Exchange account linked to one on another site that has 200 reputation points already. It's apparently supposed to reflect the fact that you're familiar with the Stack Exchange system, so you don't have to suffer through the new user period (no commenting, no upvotes, etc.).

Is there a way to add a bonus to an already-existing account? I'd think there would be, because if not, I would have waited to get involved on certain Stack Exchange sites until I reached 200 points on another site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as a quick follow up - the system appears to have been updated so that users automatically get the 100 point bonus without the need to disassociate current sites. Happened to me a few days ago.

Comment: +1: Thanks for the update!

Comment: @Firefeather: You may wish to "accept" this answer instead, since circumstances have changed.

Comment: @Al Everett: Thanks! I didn't realize you could change which answer is accepted on Meta.

Answer (score 5):

You can disassociate your current sites, and then re-associate them, thus gaining the bonus on any site where you've not yet received it.

For the former, go to your profile page, Accounts, and click Clear Associations. When next you visit the sites, you should be associated again.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!